# external program from java doesn't terminate

Tags: java, runtime, exec, external-process

When I try to execute an external program from java I use this code below :

```
Process p;
rn = Runtime.getRuntime();

String[] unzip = new String[2];

unzip[0]="unzip";

unzip[1]=archive ;

public void dezip() throws IOException{

    p = rn.exec(unzip);
    int ret = p.exitValue();

System.out.println("End of unzip method");
```

But my last `System.out` is never executed, as if we exit from `unzip` method.
The `unzip()` call does only the half of the work, only a part of my archive is unzipped.
When I use `ps -x` or `htop` from command line I see that unzip process is still here.

Help please.

Comment: This is not a true copy/paste from your code right? You talk about a method called `unzip`, is that `dezip`you mean?

Comment: Sorry ,I am using linux so unzip is a command . [link]http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_unzip.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to read the InputStream from the process. See the javadoc of [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Which states:

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for
>   standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the
>   subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

Comment: You **definitely** need to read and flush the *Output* and *Error* streams of the process. See `Process.getOutputStream` and `Process.getErrorStream`

Comment: I dont get it .i am calling unzip method and it does only half the work.Why do I need streams ?

Comment: Problem SOLVED ! I used the -qq argument for very quieter mode for unzip command. and It worked perfectly.You were right it was a buffer size problem.

Comment: It is **NOT** a buffer size problem. It is the **output** problem. As I wrote, you need to flush the output and error streams. With *-qq* unzip did not produce any output so it completed. But if there is some error that unzip reports then your `exitValue` call will block.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the unzip command is prompting for something, perhaps a warning if the file already exists and if you want to overwrite it.

Also, is that a backquote I see in the middle of a java program?

Comment: no it's not a backquote ,I am not very comfortable with stack overflow message editer so I put backquotes for my code .

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure external program doesn't wait for user input
2. Check if the the executable path is quoted when launching on Windows systems to handle directories with spaces or special characters.

PS.
I was using the `java.lang.Runtime` class but found that the [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class is far superior. You can specify current working directory, and most importantly the system environment.

Comment: my external program doesn't wait for a user input .

Comment: Executing external commands from Java seems very easy but it is actually very far from that. Did you try flushing STDINT, STDOUT and STDERR?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
p = rn.exec(unzip);
p.waitFor()
```

I hope it will change something.

Comment: No, `exitValue` waits for the child process terminates.

Comment: I tried it already. with p.waitFor() I have the same problem .